# Conda with Python3.9 using numpy in Python3.10

Tags: numpy, conda, statsmodels, arima, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to install statsmodels in Oracle Machine Learning in Conda enviroment.

My conda version is:

```
%conda
info
```

```
active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /u01/.condarc
 populated config files : /usr/share/conda/condarc.d/defaults.yaml
                          /u01/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       base environment : /usr  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /u01/.conda/pkgs
                          /var/cache/conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /u01/.conda/envs
                          /usr/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.6.8 Linux/5.4.17-2136.314.6.3.el7uek.x86_64 oracle/7.9 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 65000:65000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I created the conda enviroment with the next command:

```
%conda
create -n arima_enviroment python=3.9 xz sqlite libuuid statsmodels numpy
```

I activated the enviroment with:

```
%conda
activate arima_enviroment
```

Test the enviroment with:

```
%python
import sys
import platform

print("sys.version:", sys.version)
print("sys.version_info:", sys.version_info)
print("platform.python_version:", platform.python_version())
```

```
sys.version: 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 11:38:51) [GCC 7.5.0]
sys.version_info: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
platform.python_version: 3.9.12
```

Then I execute the next command for import the ARIMA model.

```
%python
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import arima
```

But give me the next error:

```
Fail to execute line 2: from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import arima
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1675189382222-0/zeppelin_python.py", line 206, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/u01/.conda/active_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
  File "/u01/.conda/active_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "/u01/.conda/active_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/u01/.conda/active_env/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Why conda is using Numpy in Python 3.10 folder and not the Numpy version installed in Python 3.9? How can repair it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is the result of a conflict between the numpy library included with OML4Py in Autonomous Database. Recreating the conda environment without installing numpy will resolve the problem:

%conda
create -n arima_enviroment python=3.9 xz sqlite libuuid statsmodels